# programe name .exe stops working in c IDE ,whenever i use SCANF funtion

Tags: c, scanf

programe name .exe stops working in c IDE ,whenever i use SCANF funtion....even when it builds and runs correctly.....please help me with this...i am a beginner

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int age;
    printf("please enter the age");
    scanf("%d, &age");

    if (age > 18) {
        printf("the age is grater than 18");
    }

    if  (age == 18) {
        printf("the age is equal to 18");
    }

    if (age < 18) {
        printf("the age is less than 18");
    }

}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d, &age");` - Do you  notice anything? Not speaking of the messed up braces. And how is 19 is 18?

Comment: Your `return 0` is present inside last `if`. I do not think you intended to do that.

Comment: If you use it as incorrectly as you're using it here in every program you write, then every program you write will behave the same as this one. Find a C tutorial or book, or read the documentation for `scanf()`. Or at least look at one of the 10 existing questions about using scanf() that were shown to you as possible duplicates when you posted; they're still listed over there =====>>>>>> under the Job ad as **Related**, so they're easy for you to find. Look at them and see if you spot something different about how `scanf()` is used.

Comment: the first argument to [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) is the format string, where you have to include the specifiers of the data scanf should expect, in your case `"%d"`, followed by a comma, followed a number or arguments separated by commas, containing the address of the allocated space where scanf shall store the data, in your case there is only one: `&age`. So that makes it `scanf("%d", &age);` and not what you wrote, which provides `scanf` with only one argument.

Comment: thankyou @Tardis  it works..sorry for such a silly ques...but i am a beginner know.... it takes a bit time to deal wid all these.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d, &age");
```

is

```
scanf("%d", &age);
```

Also, if you defined main as "int main()", then it has to return an int.

Comment: "*if you defined main as "int main()", then it has to return an int.*" -- No, it doesn't **have to**. §5.1.2.2.3 "Program termination": "*[...] reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.*", so `main()` is special (AFAIK starting from C99). But I agree it **should** -- relying on this special rule for `main()` is, IMHO, poor style.